# Custom ClientHttpRequestFactory in RestTemplate - Possible conflicts with @LoadBalanced?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-netflix

In my Spring Boot application I'm creating a RestTemplate with a custom ClientHttpRequestFactory so that it can use the Apache CloseableHttpClient and the HttpClientConnectionManager (so I created my RestTemplate and I explicitly call restTemplate.setRequestFactory(clientHttpRequestFactory) with my custom clientHttpRequestFactory).

I also use a eureka server for the endpoints and the @LoadBalanced annotation on the RestTemplate.

- Is there a risk of conflicts resulting from the custom
  clientHttpRequestFactory and @LoadBalanced ?
- Is @LoadBalanced annotation replacing the RestTemplate http request
  factory with it's own request factory ?

Regards

Comment: Did you have a try? Should not conflict. The LB is implemented via interceptor of restremplate.

Comment: @AddoZhang but the Ribon LB also redefines the clientHttpRequest of the restTemplate... doest it ?